# Invoke Raw Command in Host Powershell from PSCmdlet class (C#)

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am playing with class PSCmdlet.

Is there a way I can invoke a command in host powershell that executed my command?

e.g:

I would like to do a function to set some alias.

```
public void myAliases() {
// Invoke Set-Alias in host ?
}
```

I tried to instance `Powershell.Create()` and `AddCommand()` but didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to create a method in c# that can be used in powershell?

Comment: Well, Code is inside a PSCmdlet class that represents a powershell command itself, I guess. I try to create a method to encapsulate and execute raw commands like if they were defined in .psm1 module file.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your class libraries in c# and extend PSCmdlet to create methods that can be consumed directly in powershell.

To do that, you will need a method with declaration of how it will be called

```
    [Cmdlet("Lookup", "Aliases")]
    public class LookupAliases: PSCmdlet 
    {

        [Parameter(Mandatory = true,
            ValueFromPipeline = false,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = false,
            ParameterSetName = "1",
            HelpMessage = "Indicates the help message")]
        public string FirstArgument{ get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            // write your process here.
            base.ProcessRecord();
        }
    }
```

In powershell, you will need to import this dll that you created above (Compile Solution) and run in powershell

```
Lookup-Aliases -FirstArugment "value"
```

If you are looking to run powershell commands inside c#,

```
    Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runSpace.Open();

    Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

    string script = "your powershell script here";
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);

    Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Comment: Is a good answer, thank you. Is not posible to do the same but in host pipeline? That executed the command. Is not there a runspace instanced yet?

I mean I think I am having troubles because what I want is to Set-Alias specified as Global to use in my current instance of powershell.

I could do this same module using psm1 file I think faster. But I wanted to play with PSCmdlet to see purposes and limits so I am here.If you suggest something for my scenario. Thanks.